# Build a dynamic form based on user input

Tags: 6, forms, webforms

I am looking on how to build a dynamic form in Drupal 6.
Users enter the number of people attended the meeting, and the form should present a text box for each of the people attending the meeting, and containing the contact information. I would love to use webforms to do this.

What would you suggest as best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, one user need to enter informations for X persons who has to attend to your future meeting right?

To do it, I think the better way is to create a content type and use CCK with multiple field. If you need a group of fields, you can install CCK 3.X that include multiple_group module. It's a module very useful that allow you create a group of fields and the user can multiple it at infinite or as you wish.

Comment: Its about the user entering X(20) persons who have already attended the meetings and then the webform shows that many (20) textboxes to enter email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Can you safely assume that the number of needed fields will never exceed a certain value, for instance 20? In that case, I think I would create a webform with 20 fields, put a select box above it with the values 1-20 in it, and add some javascript to hide the form fields that are not needed, based on the value of the select box.